# How to prevent swipe event from firing when dragging

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop, swipe

I'm using jQueryMobile's swipe event with JQuery UI's draggable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kanesee/yrqotafo/1/) explains it best.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    delay: 300,
    cancel: false,
    start: function(event, ui) {
//      something needs to happen here?
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    },
    revert: function(is_valid_drop) {
      return true;
    }
});

$('.swipe-area').on('swiperight', function(evt) {
    alert('swiped right :('); 
});
```

Basically, when you try to drag the dark blue box to the right, the swipe event gets triggered.

I want to prevent this when dragging. What would you recommend?

(JSFiddle solution would be awesome!)

Comment: Use `.off()` to remove any `swipe` listener when dragging starts, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xg6krsng/2/ (not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use flags `on` or `off`

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/pzwwphL3/

**Code**

```
var drag; 
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {


    }
  });

$('.draggable').draggable({
    delay: 300,
    cancel: false,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        drag = "on" 
//      event.preventDefault();
//      event.stopPropagation();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        drag = "off" 
    },
    revert: function(is_valid_drop) {
      return true;
    }
});

$('.swipe-area').on('swiperight', function(evt) {
    if (drag == "off") {
    alert('swiped right :(');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did after I posted my question. I'm glad someone else confirmed it but I was also hoping for something with the event, like stopPropagation which didn't work for me